# ImportError: cannot import name 'ReCaptchaField' from 'captcha.fields'

Tags: django, recaptcha

guys im trying to run django server but i have this error     `from captcha.fields import ReCaptchaField ImportError: cannot import name 'ReCaptchaField' from 'captcha.fields'` what can i do

im trying to remove and install django-ReCaptcha but nothing change

Answer (score 2):

The confusion stems from a change made by django-recaptcha from version 3 to 4:

Version 3:

```
# usage:
from captcha.fields import ReCaptchaField

# settings.py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...,
    'captcha',
    ...
]
```

Version 4:

```
# usage
from django_recaptcha.fields import ReCaptchaField

# settings.py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...,
    'django_recaptcha',
    ...
]
```

Since you uninstalled and reinstalled it, you probably had version 3 installed first, then changed to version 4, which is why the import *as well as the name in `INSTALLED_APPS`* needs to be changed.

Answer (score 1):

You import this field from the `django_recaptcha.fields` module, so:

```
from django_recaptcha.fields import ReCaptchaField
```

Comment: Is it a typo in `from django_captcha.fields import ReCaptchaField`?  I think it should be `from django_recaptcha.fields import ReCaptchaField`.

Comment: @raphael: aarrggghh, yes. thanks!